# Java GUI - Calling value from other if statements into getSource() event

Tags: java, user-interface

So I am making a very basic cash register program currently for my college class. Basically every time I press a button it adds to a total, and when I press total it sums it all up. The the problem is that I can't seem to call the value from the variable into the total button. It always stays 0.0 even though I am making that variable have a value when I press the other events. I need to get past this point so I  can check to see if the if statements are working properly.

The end result would be a register that I can always change its total by pressing a different combination of buttons. If I press one button, it will come up with a sum. So if I press button one once, it will only be 1.50 for example. But if I press it two times, it will be 3.0. I know I probably should use a counter for each event and get the product of that counter with the predetermined value that I am setting. But right now I can't seem to get past the problem with my total button event. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BobsBurgerPanel extends JPanel
{
private int test1 = 1;
private double totalResult;
private double total1, total2, total3, total4, total5, total6;
private JButton push1, push2, push3, push4, push5, push6, total;
private JTextField text;
private JLabel label;

public BobsBurgerPanel()
{

    push1 = new JButton("Small Drink");
    push2 = new JButton("Large Drink");
    push3 = new JButton("Small Fry");
    push4 = new JButton("Large Fry");
    push5 = new JButton("Veggie Burger");
    push6 = new JButton("Bison Burger");
    total = new JButton("Total");
    label = new JLabel("        Your total is: "); 
            // Lining the text up with  the JTectfield. \t or \n do not work. 


    text = new JTextField(10);
    total.addActionListener(new TempListener());

    add(push1);
    add(push2);
    add(push3);
    add(push4);
    add(push5);
    add(push6);
    add(total);
    add(label);
    add(text);


    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
    setBackground(Color.red);

}

private class TempListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0, 
                    counter4 = 0,  counter5 = 0, counter6 = 0, counter7 = 0;
        double totalR;

            if (event.getSource() == push1)
            {
                counter1++;
                total1 = counter1 * 1.50;
            }
            if (event.getSource() == push2)
            {
                counter2++;
                total2 = counter2 * 2.10;
            }
            if (event.getSource() == push3)
            {
                counter3++;
                total3 = counter3 * 2.00;
            }
            if (event.getSource() == push4)
            {
                counter4++;
                total4 = counter4 * 2.95;
            }
            if (event.getSource() == push5)
            {
                counter5++;
                total5 = counter5 * 4.55;
            }
            if (event.getSource() == push6)
            {
                counter6++;
                total6 = counter6 * 7.95;
            }
            if (event.getSource() == total)
                totalResult =
                    (total1+total2+total3+total4+total5+total6);

        text.setText(Double.toString(totalResult));
    }
}
```

Any help or additional ideas would be great. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't know why this question has a downvote. For a newcomer, this question is clear, shows some effort on solving the issue and the code is quite readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your counter variables are declared local and therefore are `0` at every iteration. I recommend you declare them outside of your method since you need them to be incremented every time an action is performed.

Also, since your code can only be in one state at a time, you would benefit from else statements instead of just if.

Answer (score 2):

Dude you've added listener only to your `JButton total`. So the actionPerformed method **always** and **only** gets through 
    `if (event.getSource() == total)
     totalResult =(total1+total2+total3+total4+total5+total6);`
statement, because `JButton total` is the only source of click event. That's why you're getting `0` over and over again.